# Invalid range from inequality

Tags: functions, inequality

We were given this function and asked to give Range.
$$f(x)~=~\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}$$

Now I took 3 cases and deduced that $\text{Range} = \left[~0,\infty ~\right)$

Now it is obvious that if we divide two positive things and **denominator is larger, then the function returns a value smaller than $1$**.

So we had to show this:

$$\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}<1$$

I begun by 
$$\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}\geq 0$$
deliberately for this question. Taking $f(x)>0$ solves the problem. Now,

$$\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}\geq 0$$

$$\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}+1\geq 0+1$$

$$\dfrac{2+ x^2}{1+ x^2}\geq 1$$

$${2+ x^2}\geq {1+ x^2}$$

$$\implies{1}\geq \dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}$$

This gives us the Range = $[0,1]$

Which is correct? $1$ included or excluded?
Many Thanks!

Comment: Neither. The range is $[0,1)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes i mean is range $[0,1) or [0,1]$ ! how neither then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}=y\iff x^2=\dfrac y{1-y}$

Now $0\le x^2\implies0\le\dfrac y{1-y}$

$\dfrac y{1-y}=0\implies y=0$

$\dfrac y{1-y}>0\iff y(1-y)>0\iff y(y-1)<0\iff0<y<1$

---

Alternatively, $y-1=-\dfrac1{x^2+1}$ which is $<0$ as $x^2\ge0$

Comment: Thanks this is ok our teacher also told this same. but why is my deduction giving incorrect result?

Comment: @TimKrul, How come  the equality in $$\dfrac1{x^2+1}\ge0$$

Comment: You mean equality? i put x=0. now $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}=0$ so zero is included. isnt $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}\ge0$ in your answer too? just it is closed at 1.

Comment: @TimKrul, Please find my rectified comment

Comment: Yea that is the root of error! but i only applied the allowed signs on inequality?